# Wifi 6 ax2201 with kali linux live usb

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, live-usb, iwlwifi

I have an hp laptop with the intel wifi 6 ax201 wifi card.
The wifi does not function when live booting kali linux. However, wifi will function, if I boot kali linux as persistant from the usb, than reboot (back to persistancy), so I assume the drivers are there, they just requiere a reboot. The problem is, since I ran it live for testing purposes, there is no reboot for me, and persistancy is just so slow,freezes every couple of mins and so on, so I don't want to use that.
I tries downloading and installing the drivers from intel (installed according to the readme file that comes with it), but that did not work, though I am  not sure if I did that correctly, since I am a newbie.
Basically, is there a way that wifi 6 ax201 from intel could function with kali live boot without peristance?

Comment: You indicate that you are new to Linux. Please do yourself a favor, [read this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/224077) and pick a different distro afterwards.

Comment: Well, I suppose you are right, but I just wanted to use it for testing on a live usb, not as a main os or anything.  
As far as I know, I cannot “pick” a different os, because kali is the most popular os that comes with these tools pre-installed, and I know you can install the tools to other distros, but I want a live usb, and as far as I know to install anything you need a persistent usb, which is just slow. But I would like to use a different distribution, if you were to propose a way to install the tools without persistency.

Comment: I am not a complete noob (I suppose), and I thought learning how to use the tools would be a good idea, however I just couldn’t get WiFi to work despite trying to install the drivers…
I am not a total Linux newbie, I am just very new to kali.

Comment: I didn't mean any offense towards you personally - but there are loads of incredibly low-quality questions coming in here regarding Kali by people way in over their heads, so what I wrote is the "default answer".

Comment: I also didn't mean that you were offending me or anything, i just wanted to explain myself with a long explanation, bc i clearly misidentified myself as a newbie, whereas i am just new to kali as a distro, not to linux.    Thank you very much for your quick responses and answers. You are definitely right about new users and kali, and i can imagine just how many people try to use it because it is cool to be a hacker or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that the brand new weekly release (W28) actually supports my wifi card directly out of the box, and I am able to connect on a live system.
I have tried so many ways and times, that i think this truly is a change made just now. I have a very new laptop, and although the wifi card ax201 seems to be old (1-2 years i suppose), maybe mine was new, since i think intel integrates wifi to their cpus now. (might be totally wrong though)
Whatever the case, this solves my problem and question. Thanks to everybody that helped!